# How to change height of element in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hi I need help with CSS grid. I have problem with height of ***P*** element that is too small compared to Font Awesome ***I*** icon and ***H6*** header. You'll understand better when you see it. The alignment just doesn't feels good.

Here is my [Code pen](https://codepen.io/madgrip/pen/RwRpZPq):

```css
/* General settings*/ 
:root{
    --white: #fff;
    --white-transparent: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
    --red: #e34f5f;
    --red-dark: #e43a4b;
    --grey: #a3a5a5;
    --grey-light: #eee;
    --black-light: #212121;
    --black-dark: #000;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    min-width: fit-content;
}
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 1920px;
}
section{
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
section:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul, li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--white);
    list-style: none;
}
h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
h4{
    color: var(--red-dark);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0;
}
h5{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: var(--red-dark);

}
h6{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
mark{
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--red), var(--red-dark));
    background-size: 100% 34%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    color: currentColor;
}
.shadow{
    box-shadow: rgba(58, 78, 95, 0.2) 0 10px 16px, rgba(58, 78, 95, 0.05) 0 -5px 16px;
}
.shadow-blocks{
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(38, 59, 94, 0.1);
}
.grey-bg{
    background-color: var(--grey-light);
}
.container{
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;    
}
.flex-grow-equal{
    flex-grow: 1;
}



/* ACTUAL SETTINGS */

.contact-grid--container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.contact-form{
    background-color: var(--white);
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
.contact-form h6{
    font-size: 2rem;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.contact-form p{
    margin: 0.2rem 0 1rem 0;
    color: var(--grey);
    font-style: italic;
}
#contact-form{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
/* YYY Name */
.contact-form--item1{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    min-height: 2rem;
}
/* YYY Mail */
.contact-form--item2{
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
}
/* YYY Text Area */
.contact-form--item3{
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
/* YYY button */
.contact-form--item4{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--red-dark);
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .3rem;    
}
.contact-form--item4:hover{
    background-color: var(--black-light);
}

.contact-info{
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    background-color: var(--white);    
}
.contact-info-grid--container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
/* YYY icon */
.contact-info-grid--item1{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    text-align: center;
}
/* YYY h6 */
.contact-info-grid--item2{
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
}
/* YYY p */
.contact-info-grid--item3{
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
    grid-row: 3 / -1;
    color: var(--grey);
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d0d28bc357.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="contact" class="grey-bg">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3><mark>My</mark> Contact</h3>
            <p>Anim magna sunt adipisicing adipisicing Lorem reprehenderit eiusmod eiusmod qui fugiat incididunt.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-grid--container">
            <!-- YYY FORM -->
            <div class="contact-form shadow">
                <h6>Drop me a line</h6>
                <p>I'll answer all your questions.</p>
                <form id="contact-form">
                    <input type="text" name="Name" form="contactForm" class="contact-form--item1" placeholder="Name">
                    <input type="email" name="Email" class="contact-form--item2" form="contactForm" placeholder="E-mail">
                    <textarea name="Comment" form="contactForm" class="contact-form--item3" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
                    <button class="contact-form--item4">GET IN TOUCH</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- YYY INFO -->
            <div class="contact-info shadow">
                <div class="contact-info--item contact-info-grid--container">
                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x contact-info-grid--item1"></i>
                    <h6 class=" contact-info-grid--item2">Address</h6>
                    <p class=" contact-info-grid--item3">Obežná 5-3, 010 08 Žilina-Vlčince</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-info--item contact-info-grid--container">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x contact-info-grid--item1"></i>
                    <h6 class=" contact-info-grid--item2">E-mail</h6>
                    <p class=" contact-info-grid--item3">mathiashandle@gmail.com</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-info--item contact-info-grid--container">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-2x contact-info-grid--item1"></i>
                    <h6 class=" contact-info-grid--item2">Phone</h6>
                    <p class=" contact-info-grid--item3">+421 948 434 841</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here but if you want increase height of p try line-height: 2.2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `grid-template-rows: 1fr` to `grid-template-rows: 0fr`

```
.contact-info-grid--container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
}
```

`0fr` takes the height of the content. Here, .contact-info-grid--container